# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime forma

Tags: sql, laravel, datatable, controller, laravel-8

I try to save some data that it brings me from my view, which is a table, but I don't know why it throws me that error with the insert.
[result of insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9cwc.png)

this is my view:
[table of view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkLYb.png)

this is my controller:

```
    $checked_array = $_POST['id_version'];


    foreach ($request['id_version'] as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($request['id_version'][$key], $checked_array)) 
        {

            $soft_instal = new Software_instalacion;
            $soft_instal->id_instalacion             = $instalaciones->id;
            $soft_instal->id_historial               = $historial->id;
            $soft_instal->id_usuario                 = $request->id_usuario;
            $soft_instal->id_version                 = $_POST['id_version'][$key];
            $soft_instal->obs_software               = $_POST['obs_software'][$key];
            $soft_instal->id_tipo_venta              = $_POST['id_tipo_venta'][$key];
            $soft_instal->save();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id_tipo_venta` seems to be an empty string which is apparently not valid.

You can try debugging what you get in :

```php
var_dump($_POST['id_tipo_venta'][$key]);
die;
```

Your database field expects to receive an integer. Therefore, using the intval() function can solve your problem.

Indeed, I think your code returns an alphanumeric string.

Therefore, the code below will return 0 in all cases if no version is returned (not set, string or simply null):

```php
$soft_instal->id_tipo_venta = intval($_POST['id_tipo_venta'][$key]);
```

On the other hand, intval() will always convert to int, so a decimal will be converted, example :

```php
intval("1.1") // returns 1
intval("v1.1") // returns 0
```

If this is not the desired behavior, maybe you should think about changing your database type.

**EDIT :**
Of course, you can also set the value as null **if you prefer** to 0. You must allow nullable values in your database.

Comment: the value of [id_tipo_venta] is part of the select that brings the ids of a table, that is, it can be 1,2,3...

It brings these values ​​in the form of an array of the view, that's why I execute the foreach

Answer (score -2):

`id_tipo_venta` can not be empty, try with some number or change type column to `varchar` in the database

Comment: Why change the type of the field in this case? if it is supposed to be an integer it should not be represented by a string. if it is supposed to be optional, then it should be nullable not converted to a string.

Comment: then have use 0 and not use ''. 
in SQL can not use '' in the integer column because '' is a string